# Не отображается межстраничное объявление

Tags: android

Не отображается межстраничное объявление при переходе в другое Activity. В activity "About" добавил следующий код:

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ид_объявления");
// Создаём запрос к AdMob
AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
// Начинаем загружать объявление
interstitial.loadAd(adRequesti);
displayInterstitial();
```

и метод

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
}
```

В манифест добавил

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Ну и в gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
```

Сервисы гугл плей установил тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вызываете метод отображения рекламы сразу после начала её загрузки. Она не успевает загрузиться и, засим, не показывается. Вызовите метод показа позже, например при нажатии на к-л кнопку